# Inheritance, Static, and confusion

Tags: java

I have 3 Java books, and use online resources, including the posts on this website, also but something is just not clicking. New too programming in general and not the brightest bulb so please try and dumb down the responses if at all possible. Going to try and explain in detail the best I can, sorry if this is a long post and **THANK YOU FOR YOUR TIME**. Also, am using [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) IDE

**GOAL:**
I'm trying to create a simple "Game" that implements a GUI, you click 1 of 3 JButtons to perform an action, and above the JButtons is a JTextArea used to relay all the information to the User.

***PROBLEM:*** I'm not referencing objects in other classes correctly and creating static methods and variables to compensate (I think) But please take a look and let me know what else I'm doing incorrectly I need comments and criticism from people that know whats up.

**SIDE NOTE:**
Its buggy and a lot has been turned into a "static" method or variables in order to use between classes. When it came time to create a new "Level" I couldn't recycle my enemy ArrayList and load new enemies in it due to the static nature of it all. I will post the working version but I have started to rebuild it for practice makes perfect, and possibly upgrade my code.

- As far as structure, should each "Level" be its own class, should all the levels be in an ArrayList like the enemies, and should I have 1 class that works as the game loop?
- - Is there a generic best way when creating something or as long as it works it doesn't matter? (opinions please)

I have ***6 Packages*** and ***13 Classes*** which is a lot of code, so I will just print the classes I believe are of importance to the situation.

***Main Class:***

```
package Primary;
import GUI.PrimaryFrame;
import Game.Loop;
/**
* Created by Thunderfoot on 8/4/2016. Keep Growing!
*/
public class Alpha {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Instantiate our GUI
    PrimaryFrame frameGUI = new PrimaryFrame();
    frameGUI.buildGUI();
    //Instantiate our game loop
    Loop.newGame();
   }
}
```

***GUI:***

```
package GUI;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

/**
* Graphical User Interface requires:
* 1 JFrame (PrimaryFrame)
* 4 JPanel (outputPanel, characterStatsPanel, topButtonPanel, bottomButtonPanel)
* 3 JTextArea (output, playerStats, enemyStats)
* 1 JScrollPane (output)
* 3 JButton (attackButton, kickButton, powAttButton)
*/
public class PrimaryFrame extends JFrame {

private OutputPanel outPanel = new OutputPanel();
private StatsPanel statPanel = new StatsPanel();
private TopButtons topPanel = new TopButtons();
private BottomButtons botPanel = new BottomButtons();

//Constructor
public PrimaryFrame() {
    //frame
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new BoxLayout(getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    Dimension FRAME_MIN = new Dimension(400, 600);
    setMinimumSize(FRAME_MIN);
    Dimension FRAME_MAX = new Dimension(600, 800);
    setMaximumSize(FRAME_MAX);
    setTitle("Generic Fighting Game");
    getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);

}

public void buildGUI() {

    //Add components and spacing
    add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(8, 8)));
    add(outPanel);
    add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(8, 8)));
    add(statPanel);
    add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(8, 8)));
    add(topPanel);
    add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(8, 8)));
    add(botPanel);
    add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(8, 8)));


    //Set attributes
    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);


   }

}
```

***Output Panel:***

```
package GUI;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultCaret;
import java.awt.*;

/**
* Created by Thunderfoot on 8/4/2016. Keep Growing!
*/
public class OutputPanel extends JPanel {

//Class variables
public static JTextArea output;


OutputPanel() {

    Font myFont = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 16);
    BoxLayout outFlow = new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.X_AXIS);
    setLayout(outFlow);
    setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 100));
    setMaximumSize(new Dimension(600, 300));

    //TextArea
    output = new JTextArea(1,50);
    output.setLineWrap(true);
    output.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    output.setEditable(false);
    output.setFont(myFont);
    JScrollPane outputScroll = new JScrollPane(output, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    outputScroll.isWheelScrollingEnabled();
    //TextArea always scroll to bottom after update
    DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret)output.getCaret();
    caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);

    //Add components and spacing
    add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(8, 8)));
    add(outputScroll, CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(8, 8)));

   }
}
```

***Game Loop:***

```
package Game;

import Characters.BasicEnemy;
import Characters.UserCharacter;
import GUI.BottomButtons;
import GUI.TopButtons;
import Levels.Level_One;
import Levels.Tutorial;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Loop {

//Class variables
public static UserCharacter player;
public static ArrayList<BasicEnemy> enemyList;
public static int currLevel = 0;

public static void newGame() {
    combatDisabled();
    switch (currLevel) {
        case 0:
            Tutorial tutorial = new Tutorial();
            tutorial.runTutorial();
            combatEnabled();
            break;
        case 1:
            Level_One lvl1 = new Level_One();
            lvl1.runLevelOne();
            combatEnabled();
            break;
    }
}

public static void combatEnabled() {
    TopButtons.attackButton.setEnabled(true);
    TopButtons.kickButton.setEnabled(true);
}

public static void combatDisabled() {
    TopButtons.attackButton.setEnabled(false);
    TopButtons.kickButton.setEnabled(false);
    BottomButtons.powAttButton.setEnabled(false);
  }
}
```

***Level 1:***

```
package Levels;

import Characters.BasicEnemy;
import Characters.UserCharacter;
import CombatSystem.Combat;
import GUI.OutputPanel;
import Game.Loop;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Tutorial {

public void runTutorial() {

    //Instance variables
    Loop.player = new UserCharacter(100, 10);
    BasicEnemy enemy0 = new BasicEnemy(100, 5);
    BasicEnemy enemy1 = new BasicEnemy(100, 5);
    BasicEnemy enemy2 = new BasicEnemy(100, 5);
    Loop.enemyList = new ArrayList<>();
    Loop.enemyList.add(enemy0);
    Loop.enemyList.add(enemy1);
    Loop.enemyList.add(enemy2);
    OutputPanel.output.append("Greetings player! Use the buttons at the bottom of the screen to fight your opponent.");
    Combat.statusUpdate();
    Loop.combatEnabled();
  }
}
```

***Class that handles combat:***

```
package CombatSystem;

import GUI.BottomButtons;
import GUI.OutputPanel;
import GUI.StatsPanel;
import Game.Loop;

import java.util.Random;

public class Combat {

//Player stats
private static int playerCurrHealth = Loop.player.getHealth();
private static int playerCurrRage = Loop.player.getRageMeter();
private static int playerAttack = Loop.player.getAttackPower();
private static int playerKick = Loop.player.getKickPower();
private static int playerPowAttack = Loop.player.getRagePower();

//Enemy stats
private static int enemyCurrHealth = Loop.enemyList.get(0).getHealth();
private static int enemyCurrRage = Loop.enemyList.get(0).getRageMeter();
private static int enemyAttack = Loop.enemyList.get(0).getAttackPower();

//Fighting
private static boolean fighting = true;

public Combat() {

}


//Update status fields
public static void statusUpdate() {
    StatsPanel.playerStats.setText(" <" + playerCurrHealth + "> [" + playerCurrRage + "] ");
    StatsPanel.enemyStats.setText(" <" + enemyCurrHealth + "> [" + enemyCurrRage + "] ");
}

//Basic attack
public static void basicAttack() {
    if (fighting) {
        playerBasicAttack();
        if (enemyCurrHealth <= 0) {
            death();
        } else {
            enemyBasicAttack();
            if (playerCurrHealth <= 0) {
                death();
            }
        }
    }
}

//Player combat systems
private static void playerBasicAttack() {
    OutputPanel.output.append("\n Your attack does " + playerAttack + " damage to the enemy!");
    enemyCurrHealth -= playerAttack;
    gainPlayerRage();
    gainEnemyRage();
    statusUpdate();
}

//Player kick attack
public static void playerKickAttack() {
    OutputPanel.output.append("\n Your kick does " + playerKick + " damage to the enemy!");
    enemyCurrHealth -= playerKick;
    gainPlayerRage();
    gainEnemyRage();
    statusUpdate();
    Random random = new Random();
    int kickChance = random.nextInt(100) + 1;
    if (kickChance >= 60) {
        OutputPanel.output.append("\n Your kick has stunned the enemy!");
    } else {
        enemyBasicAttack();
        gainEnemyRage();
        gainPlayerRage();
        statusUpdate();
    }
}


//Player power attack
public static void playerPowAttack() {
    OutputPanel.output.append("\n Your POWER ATTACK does " + playerPowAttack + " damage to the enemy!");
    enemyCurrHealth -= playerPowAttack;
    playerCurrRage = 0;
    gainEnemyRage();
    statusUpdate();
    BottomButtons.powAttButton.setEnabled(false);
}


private static void gainPlayerRage() {
    if (playerCurrRage < 100) {
        playerCurrRage += 5;
        if (playerCurrRage >= 100) {
            playerCurrRage = 100;
            BottomButtons.powAttButton.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            BottomButtons.powAttButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}

//Enemy combat systems
private static void enemyBasicAttack() {
    OutputPanel.output.append("\n Enemy's attack does " + enemyAttack + " damage to you!");
    playerCurrHealth -= enemyAttack;
    gainEnemyRage();
    gainPlayerRage();
    statusUpdate();

}

private static void gainEnemyRage() {
    if (enemyCurrRage < 100) {
        enemyCurrRage += 5;
    } else {
        enemyCurrRage = 100;
    }
}

//END GAME
private static void death() {
    if (playerCurrHealth <= 0) {
        Loop.combatDisabled();
        fighting = false;
        loseGame();
    } else if (enemyCurrHealth <= 0) {
        if (!Loop.enemyList.isEmpty()) {
            Loop.enemyList.remove(0);
            OutputPanel.output.append("\nYou have killed an enemy!");
            statusUpdate();
            fighting = true;
        } else {
            fighting = false;
            Loop.combatDisabled();
            winGame();
        }
    }
}

private static void winGame() {
    OutputPanel.output.setText("You won!");
    Loop.combatDisabled();
    Loop.currLevel++;
    Loop.enemyList.clear();
    Loop.newGame();
}

private static void loseGame() {
    OutputPanel.output.setText("You lost!");
    Loop.combatDisabled();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, the right way to do this is to create an instance of a class that is called a **controller**. A controller is an object that handles references to other objects and handles out the tasks to be done. So, in your main, you do something like

```
GameController cont = new GameController();
```

Then, if you need something that the controller requires access to, just link it inside the controller:

```
GUI gui = new GUI();
cont.setGUI(gui);
```

Also, whenever something will need to access the controller to do its work, you need to provide it with the controller:

```
gui.setController(controller);
```

This way, you provide abstraction - you do not call eg. GUI drawing from within your player character, you just create methods within the controller such as say `handlePlayerInput(...)` and the controller knows what objects to call and what methods to handle.

Answer (score 0):

"Everything static" is not a bad programming paradigm per se, however it usually signals heavy-coupled and inflexible architecture. For example, should you have two `enemyLists`, what would you do? Another static field would probably do but it would require a lot of copy-paste for all things that use `enemyList` right now. Copy-pasting is usually the thing you want to avoid so as to make long-term maintenance easier.

Better architectures encapsulate things into meaningful abstractions, either object-oriented or somehow else representing modules with single responsibilities. Game logic and rendering are usually separate things. As is said in a another answer by @PiotrWilkin, many implementations encapsulate top-level components into a controller while those components themselves manage other related things.

If you are interested in software design and architecture, I would suggest reading the following two classics:

- [Principles and Patterns](https://web.archive.org/web/20150906155800/http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/Principles_and_Patterns.pdf) by Robert C. Martin, a detailed explanation of SOLID design principles, simple to learn yet hard to master concepts that together help making rock-solid software architectures.
- [Design Patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) by Erich Gamma, Richard Helm, Ralph Johnson and John Vlissides with a foreword by Grady Booch. This is a dictionary-like book, describing patterns commonly applied in software design.